# Best way to determine mime type of a file in java?

Tags: java, image, mime-types

Curious what the best way is in Java to get the mime-type of a file. It should actually inspect the file because filenames aren't an accurate indicator.

Currently I'm using the following which seems to be very hit or miss

```
  is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
  String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
  if(mimeType == null) {
    throw new IOException("can't get mime type of image");
  }
```

Comment: Still believe your way is great for most cases.

Comment: I used the class that was posted as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140531/293280

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`URLConnection#guessContentTypeFromStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) or [`...FromName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName%28java.lang.String%29) is indeed the best what you can get in the standard Java SE API. There are however 3rd party libraries like [jMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) which does its work better than `URLConnection#guessXXX()` methods.

```
String mimeType = Magic.getMagicMatch(file, false).getMimeType();
```

This supports a more wide range of mime types.

Comment: @BalusC What can you say about this SO question [check file of MIME-type with JMimeMagic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325047/check-file-of-mime-type-with-jmimemagic)?

Comment: @BalusC i tried to use it but with docx files it returns that the mime type is application/zip which is not correct

Answer (score 6):

Following link has a good comparison of various ways of getting the Mime type of a file (it includes libraries like: Apache Tika, JMimeMagic etc. with some native code too):
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String getContentType(String filename)
    {
        String g = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename);
        if( g == null)
        {
            g = MimetypesFileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename);
        }
        return g;
    }
```