# java library to find the mime type from file content

Tags: java, mime, file-type

I am searching for a java library which tells you the mime type by looking at the file content(byte array). I found this project using jmimemagic and it no longer supports newer file types (eg. MS word docx format) as it is inactive now (from 2006).

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/files/mime-util/mime-util-2.1.3/

Comment: What about the solutions [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html). Do they not work for you?

Comment: mime util is not working for microsoft docx files. Mime util is reporting it as application/zip. I am expect more specific one, something like application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document. I found apache tika working for me.

Comment: The code snippet shown in the link works but not for files like Microsoft docx.

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate to the referenced question because the author asks explicitly for detection by the file content whereas the solutions for the other question refer to a file (inclusive file name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Apache tika for content detection. Please find the link below. http://tika.apache.org/0.8/detection.html. We have so many jar dependencies which you can find when you build tika using maven

```
        ByteArrayInputStream bai = new ByteArrayInputStream(pByte);
        ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        try {
              parser.parse(bai, contenthandler, metadata);

        } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        System.out.println("Mime: " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
        return metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Comment: Please NOTE: As with most Apache libraries, this one will impregnate your dependency to oblivion. It could be a concern if you are using the shade maven plugin to create an uber jar.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe useful for someone, who needs the most used office formats as well (and does not use Apache Tika):

```
public class MimeTypeUtils {

    private static final Map<String, String> fileExtensionMap;

    static {
        fileExtensionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // MS Office
        fileExtensionMap.put("doc", "application/msword");
        fileExtensionMap.put("dot", "application/msword");
        fileExtensionMap.put("docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        fileExtensionMap.put("dotx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("docm", "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("dotm", "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xlt", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xla", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xltx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xlsm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xltm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xlam", "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("xlsb", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        fileExtensionMap.put("pot", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        fileExtensionMap.put("pps", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ppa", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        fileExtensionMap.put("pptx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
        fileExtensionMap.put("potx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ppsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ppam", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("pptm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("potm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ppsm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12");
        // Open Office
        fileExtensionMap.put("odt", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ott", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("oth", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odm", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odg", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics");
        fileExtensionMap.put("otg", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odp", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation");
        fileExtensionMap.put("otp", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ods", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet");
        fileExtensionMap.put("ots", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odc", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odf", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odb", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database");
        fileExtensionMap.put("odi", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image");
        fileExtensionMap.put("oxt", "application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension");
    }

    public static String getContentTypeByFileName(String fileName) {
        // 1. first use java's buildin utils
        FileNameMap mimeTypes = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
        String contentType = mimeTypes.getContentTypeFor(fileName);
        // 2. nothing found -> lookup our in extension map to find types like ".doc" or ".docx"
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(contentType)) {
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
            contentType = fileExtensionMap.get(extension);
        }
        return contentType;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change `if (!StringUtils.hasText(contentType)) {` to `if (StringUtils.isBlank(contentType)) {`. Thanks for the codez!

Answer (score 2):

I use `javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap`. It starts with a small set: `$JRE_HOME/lib/content-types.properties`, but you can add you own. Create a file `mime.types` in the format shown in `MimetypesFileTypeMap`'s javadoc (I started with a large list from the net, massaged it, and added types I found missing). Now you can add that in your code by opening your `mime.types` file and adding its contents to your map. However the easier solution is to add your `mime.types` file to the `META-INF` of your jar. `java.activation` will pick that up automagically.