# How to know the filetype?

Tags: java, android, file, file-type

I want to know whether the file is **Audio**(`mp3`,`aac`, etc), **Video**(`mp4`,`wmv`,`3gp`,etc), **Document**(`txt`,`rtf`,`doc`,`docx`,`xls`,`xlsx`,`ppt`,`html` etc) or Unknown (with no extension and other custom extension specific for one single application in the near future)

I need to implement it in Android. I think I could find the extension of file and identifying its type? Or do I not need to know the extension?

I just want to know the file-type.

Comment: I used the class that was posted as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140531/293280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try to guess the file type from the filename extension using [`guessContentTypeFromName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName%28java.lang.String%29), or you can try to guess the file type from the content using [`guessContentTypeFromStream()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Comment: If you look at the source of `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream()` you'll see it only knows about HTML, XML, zip files, and GIF images. It can't identify most of the file types the question asks for. `guessContentTypeFromName()` has a larger database, but the questioner specifically asked to identify files with no extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.FileNameMap;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class FileUtils {

public static String getMimeType(String fileUrl)
  throws java.io.IOException {
      FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
      String type = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(fileUrl);

     return type;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      System.out.println(FileUtils.getMimeType("file://c:/temp/test.TXT"));
     // output :  text/plain
   }
}
```

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

Answer (score 0):

on Android, you can try something like this:

```
File f = <YOUR FILE>

String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
String fileExtension = null;
int dotPos = path.lastIndexOf('.');
if (0 <= dotPos) {
    fileExtension = path.substring(dotPos + 1);
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileExtension )) {
    String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension.toLowerCase());
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mime)) {
        if (mime.startsWith("text")) {
        // TEXT FILE
        } else if (mime.startsWith("image")) {
        // IMAGE FILE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mime-util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/) library. My sample code will get the mime type of the file.

```
    String imagePath = "/tmp/test.txt";
    File file = new File(imagePath);

    if (MimeUtil.getMimeDetector(MagicMimeMimeDetector.class.getName()) == null)  {
        MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector(MagicMimeMimeDetector.class.getName());
    }
    Collection<MimeType> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(file);
    for (MimeType mimeType : mimeTypes) {
        System.out.println(mimeType.getMediaType());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to find out file extension is using `lastIndexOf('.')` assuming file name contains extension. Check the following code

```
String fileName = "test.jpg";
int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
String fileExtension = fileName.substring(i+1);
Log.v("FILE EXTENSION: ",fileExtension);
```