# MIME-type checking with JMimeMagic - MagicMatchNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, mime-types

I need check `currentFile` of MIME-type. If result is success and file have MIME-type `return true`. If wasn't checking succed `return false`.
With this goal I use [JMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/).
I try do this [according this post](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html)

Output from this code is - `net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatchNotFoundException`

You need have **JDK 7** - for changing File to byte[] at this way(`Files.readAllBytes(path)`).

**Code:**

```
    class ProbeContentTypeCheker implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File currentFile) {
        String mimeType = null;
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch(data);
            mimeType = match.getMimeType();
        } catch (MagicParseException | MagicMatchNotFoundException
                | MagicException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null != mimeType) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output (only if it's "wrong" type):**

```
 net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatchNotFoundException
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic.getMagicMatch(Magic.java:222)
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic.getMagicMatch(Magic.java:170)
    at task.ProbeContentTypeCheker.check(FileScan.java:357)
    at task.FolderScan.findFiles(FileScan.java:223)
    at task.FolderScan.findFiles(FileScan.java:215)
    at task.FolderScan.run(FileScan.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

If file is "ok" type => output to console normal. But after some time arise another **exception**:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.String.toCharArray(String.java:2753)
    at org.apache.oro.text.perl.Perl5Util.match(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatcher.testRegex(MagicMatcher.java:663)
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatcher.testInternal(MagicMatcher.java:433)
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatcher.test(MagicMatcher.java:341)
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic.getMagicMatch(Magic.java:208)
    at net.sf.jmimemagic.Magic.getMagicMatch(Magic.java:170)
    at task.ProbeContentTypeCheking.check(FileScan.java:384)
    at task.FolderScan.findFiles(FileScan.java:228)
    at task.FolderScan.findFiles(FileScan.java:225)
    at task.FolderScan.findFiles(FileScan.java:225)
    at task.FolderScan.run(FileScan.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Question:**

- How do solve this arises of exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMimeMagic [0.1.2](http://jcenter.bintray.com/jmimemagic/jmimemagic/0.1.2/jmimemagic-0.1.2.pom?direct) depends on Commons Logging 1.0.4
A [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-is-the-difference-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classnotfoundexception) means that the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The solution would be to add the commons-logging-1.0.4.jar to your classpath.

Note that JMimeMagic has other [3rd party dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jmimemagic/jmimemagic/0.1.2):

1. Jakarta ORO 2.0.8
2. Log4j 1.2.8
3. Xerces 2.4.0 (optional)
4. xml-apis 2.0.2
5. xmlParserAPIs 2.0.2

**Update - MagicMatchNotFoundException**

The [MagicMatchNotFoundException](http://jmimemagic.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/jmimemagic/MagicMatchNotFoundException.html) is thrown if no mime type match is found for the provided data.
You can set the log level of `net.sf.jmimemagic` to DEBUG to get more information about what is going on

**Update 2 - OutOfMemoryError**

The OOM looks related to the behavior of JmimeMagic. In some cases it will try to run a regular expression against the entire byte array input to find the magic number match. See this reported [issue](https://jira.nuxeo.com/browse/NXP-9337) for the Nuxeo Enterprise Platform.
I think you can solve this issue by limiting the size of the byte array you pass to `getMagicMatch`

Comment: Does `commons-logging-1.0.4.jar` means `Log4j 1.2.8`?

Comment: I added library `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`. Output to console(in the red color): `мар 11, 2013 2:00:36 PM net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicParser endElement
INFO: endElement(): not adding invalid matcher '320 kBits'` ... `NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/oro/text/perl/Perl5Util`

Comment: you need to add all the other libraries I specified in my answer

Comment: I added all .jar files. Output to console: `net.sf.jmimemagic.MagicMatchNotFoundException`. How do solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace to your question

Comment: Do you get this exception for every checked file?

Comment: Only for every "bad" file. If it's "ok" file => output at normal way. And result this run is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Why does this happen?

Comment: How does circumvent this monent?

Comment: Take a look at the class on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140531/293280